# Log Files for angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular application, I want to keep track of some activities of the user and also maintain logs of debug/error statements in `Angular`. For this, I want to implement logs.

My Business logic is written in Java which is a `REST API` so don't want to use that for logging debug/error statements of another layer - Angular. I can across `Apache's Log4JS` but can not seem to integrate it in my Angular 5 app, nor very sure if this is the right thing. My Angular app is deployed on an `AWS EC2` node and that's why I want to keep track of logs if something breaks.

Comment: Can't you post your logs to the java rest API?

Comment: I am not promoting any product but there are already solutions such as datadog , stackdriver for the same. You can check there implementation as demos for many cleint side technologies

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Amazon Cloud watch to refer so in case your focus error or result you can track with that then you don't need to enter in to making any other sort of wrapper or code change. Its hard to give direct solution till don't get idea that how many aspect you wish to track in log

feel free to refer this as ready to run service as tool https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html

Comment: Thanks for replying, Chetan. I looked into Cloud Watch but I don't want to track only errors in my application. I want to keep track of everything that's happening on my website, I figured maintaining logs would be a way to go. What I want to understand here is that what is the recommended way of maintaining logs in Angular 5 deployed on a server (may or may not be AWS).